# How to get selected option using Selenium WebDriver with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selecteditem, selected

How to get selected option using Selenium WebDriver with Python:

Someone have a solution for a `getFirstSelectedOption`?

I'm using this to get the select element:

```
try:
    FCSelect = driver.find_element_by_id('FCenter')
    self.TestEventLog = self.TestEventLog + "<br>Verify Form Elements: F Center Select found"
except NoSuchElementException:
    self.TestEventLog = self.TestEventLog + "<br>Error: Select FCenter element not found"
```

Is there an equivalent or something close to 'getFirstSelectedOption' like this:

```
try:
    FCenterSelectedOption = FCenterSelect.getFirstSelectedOption()
    self.TestEventLog = self.TestEventLog + "<br>Verify Form Elements: F Center Selected (First) found"
except NoSuchElementException:
    self.TestEventLog = self.TestEventLog + "<br>Error: Selected Option element not found"
```

Then I would like to Verify the Contents with a `getText` like:

```
try:
    FCenterSelectedOptionText = FCenterSelectedOption.getText()
    self.TestEventLog = self.TestEventLog + "<br>Verify Form Elements: FCenter Selected Option Text found"
except NoSuchElementException:
    self.TestEventLog = self.TestEventLog + "<br>Error: Selected Option Text element not found"

if FCenterSelectedOptionText == 'F Center Option Text Here':
    self.TestEventLog = self.TestEventLog + "<br>Verify Form Elements: F Center Selected Option Text found"
else:
    self.TestEventLog = self.TestEventLog + "<br>Error: F Center 'Selected' Option Text not found"
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is something that `selenium` makes it easy to deal with - the [`Select`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) class:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('FCenter'))
selected_option = select.first_selected_option
print selected_option.text
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: "if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tag_name'"