# How to get the Selected Text through Beautifulsoup in Python

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I am parsing an page through Beautifulsoup in Python. The page ( link : https://services.ecourts.gov.in/ecourtindia/cases/s_order.php?state=D&state_cd=1&dist_cd=37) has a select box.

I would like to get the selected text from the select box.

Here is the HTML text after selecting an option :

```
<select name="court_complex_code" id="court_complex_code" style="width: 250px;height:21px;" onchange="funCourtEstChange();">
<option value="0">Select Court Complex</option>
<option value="1@2">Mumbai City Sessions Court</option>
<option value="119@1">Mumbai, City Civil Court</option><option value="121@5">Sewree, City Civil Court</option>
<option value="133@3,4">Dindoshi, City Civil Court</option>
</select>
```

Notice the attribute, `selected` is not set to `True`. It uses Javascript to obtain the selected value using the following code :

```
var court_complex_code=document.getElementById('court_complex_code').value;
```

I would like to get the selected text ( & value) through Beautifulsoup. Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: But you don't even know which one is seletected?

Comment: That's correct. I am doing it in conjunction with Selenium. The user would select it manually. I would like to know which one is selected. Through `Javascript` it is possible as shown above.

Comment: Will it be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30872875/5588279

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sraw, It really helped. Can you please convert this into an answer, so that It might help others as well

Comment: As you can see, it is an existing answer, so what I really should do is to mark your question as duplicated...